# Why is a setup function in Playwright test being called twice and how to ensure a single call?

Tags: javascript, typescript, debugging, testing, playwright

Description:
I'm encountering an issue where a function in my Playwright test setup is being called twice, even though it's expected to be called only once.

Context:
I'm working on a TypeScript project that utilizes the Playwright testing framework (@playwright/test) for end-to-end testing. In my test setup, I have a function named `getInsureApplications()` that generates test data for my test cases.

Code Snippets:

```
// test.spec.ts
import { test } from '@playwright/test'

export const insureApplications = getInsureApplications()
function getInsureApplications (): any[] {
  console.log('...getInsureApplications() called...')
  return ['A', 'B']
}

for (let i = 0; i < insureApplications.length; i++) {
  test.only(`Email ${i}`, async () => {
    // Test logic...
  })
}
```

Expected Behavior:
I expect `getInsureApplications()` to be called once during the test setup, as it initializes the `insureApplications` array with test data.

Actual Behavior:
However, upon running the tests, I noticed that `getInsureApplications()` is being called twice, as evidenced by the multiple log entries in the console.

Node version: v20.11.0
Playwright version: 1.41.2

Comment: I think this is normal behavior--the test suite runs the file to detect tests, then runs it again to run the tests. Is there a problem with this function running twice? It should be idempotent.

Comment: Yes, there is a problem with this function running twice.
getInsureApplications() is responsible for producing random data for tests.
Based on this generated test data tests will be prepared.
Both times it will produce a different set of random data. Hence tests are failing.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Can you share that code so it's clearer what your actual use case is?